# Ошибка при запуске exe файла

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Создал небольшую программу с GUI для работы с геоданными. Решил создать exe файл , но при его запуске возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\timna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\timna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\timna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
  File "site-packages\fiona\_loading.py", line 54, in add_gdal_dll_directories
  File "os.py", line 1109, in add_dll_directory
OSError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно: ''
[11276] Failed to execute script main
```

Строка 11 файла main.py на которой было сгенерировано исключение:

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

В чем может быть причина?

Спасибо за помощь и ответы!

Comment: Прикрепите , пожалуйста , строчку на которую сгенерировано данное исключение ```File "main.py", line 11, in <module>```

Comment: @shalor1k здравствуйте,прикрепил, импортировал библиотеку

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вызвана несовместимостью зависимостей fiona и gdal. Удалите geopanda's через conda. Он также удалит fiona.Сделайте `conda uninstall geopandas`; Сделайте `conda install fiona=1.6`. Сделай `conda search fiona`заранее и посмотрите, доступен ли он для вашей версии python. Если нет, создайте новую среду для этой версии python (например,`create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda`)

Потом `pip install geopandas`

Наконец, попробуйте `import geopandas`
и посмотрите, появляется ли по-прежнему ошибка.
Оригинал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749254/error-in-importing-geopandas)